# Function that generates "n" functions and adds them

Tags: python

I'm looking to write code where when I type in any natural number, call it "n", It generates "n" functions and adds them into a composite function. For a simple example, let's say the function I want to add "n" times is f(x) = 2(x). This is the following code and error. How can I fix this?

```
def functiongen(n):
    return 2(x) + (2(x))*(n-1)

functiongen(2)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-4132b74576dd> in <module>
      2     return 2(x) + (2(x))*(n-1)
      3 
----> 4 functiongen(2)

<ipython-input-73-4132b74576dd> in functiongen(n)
      1 def functiongen(n):
----> 2     return 2(x) + (2(x))*(n-1)
      3 
      4 functiongen(2)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Thanks!

Comment: the issue seems that You have put integer in front of paranthesis which may make Python think that You are calling it as a function, also that is not how mathematical functions work in python (at least not without importing some kind of a module if it even exists)

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You need to repeat your tutorial materials to learn how the language elements and syntax work.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot you just multiply? Adding n times is multiplying with n. First define the f function, and another function `functiongen`

```
def f(x):
    # ...

def functiongen(n):
    return f() * n
```